# Kubernetes hostPort: invisible to lsof?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, lsof

I am playing around with my own small Kubernetes cluster.

Something that I don't understand so far is how to see all open ports (= everything my Pods are listening on).

I use Traefik as ingress with *hostPorts :80 and :443* and I can see it listening to *:80* and *:443* when I run `sudo lsof -i`.

However, I also have GitLab running as Pod, and assigned it a *hostPort* (54321) that points to the Pods' port *:22*. I use this for git cloning.

Both Pods have a *nodeSelector* to run only on the master (...yes, I know.).

GitLab's *hostPort :54321* doesn't show up with `sudo lsof -i`. Why is that?
I can't really explain that with my limited knowledge.

In terms of configuration, the only difference of the Traefik Pods vs. the Gitlab Pod is that for Traefik, the *hostPorts* point to the same port in the Pod (*:80->:80*, *:443->:443*) while for the Gitlab Pod, they differ (*:54321->:22*).

Can anybody explain this to me? Why can't I trust *lsof* in this case?

Thanks in advance!

ps. the port is definitely open and listening

Answer (score 1):

> GitLab's hostPort :54321 doesn't show up with `sudo lsof -i`. Why is that? I can't really explain that with my limited knowledge.

`lsof`  lists  information about **files**<sup>1</sup> opened by **processes**.

There is **no process** on the host that keeps the hostPort open and thus nothing to display for `lsof`.

Probably there is only a netfilter (`iptables`) rule that forwards traffic on that port to your Gitlab Pod. Check with `sudo iptables-save` and/or `sudo iptables -L -v -n` , `sudo iptables -L -v -n  -t security -t nat -t mangle`

---

Where very broadly an open file may be a regular file, a directory, a block special file, a character special file, an executing text reference, a library, a stream or a network file (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX domain socket.)